# How to set boolean in xml-action script

Tags: moqui

I am trying to set a flag so I do something like this:

```
<set field="existingFound" value="false" type="Boolean"/>
```

but the following line prints "true" in the log:

```
<log message="storeProperty, existingFound (0):  ${existingFound}"/>
```

What is the best way to set flags?

Answer (score 2):

The set.@value attribute is interpreted as a Groovy String (GString) so any non-empty value will be interpreted as true. The set.@from attribute is interpreted as a Groovy expression, so simply using from="false" instead of value="false" will get the desired result.

To see the generated Groovy code from an XML actions block you can write code that will cause an error and then the script will be logged, or you can change the log4j.xml file to turn on "debug" level logging for the XmlActions class (the latest log4j.xml file in the GitHub repository has an example of this). Looking at the Groovy code generated from the XML elements is a good way to track down issues when what is happening just doesn't make sense.